# Which data structure to use in Java for the following scenario?

Tags: java

I have a set of Elements which are prefixes. I've to write a Java method in such a way that whenever it gets an input verify in which prefix it belongs to and return true or false if it matches with any prefixes. 
Elements are

```
1900
1901
1902
1903
17082
```

Input will be

```
1900123445
1901334455
1800777777
...
```

Which Data Structure I can use so that it'll not hit the performance. Because the input numbers will be up to 50million at once.

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the prefixes all the same length?

Comment: That sounds like a case for a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I don't think that there's a (public) Trie implementation in the Java SE APIs, however. (Don't know of a "cannonical" third-party implementation either).

Comment: Now that we know that the prefixes can have different lengths, I've edited my answer. Are they all numerical?

Answer (score 2):

If possible, test each of these methods and see which is the fastest in context. It will probably depend on a variety of factors, and I can't really predict which one will work best in your specific use case.

#### Option 0 (use this if you have very few prefixes)

The easiest option: store your prefixes in a linked list and check against each one using `input.startsWith(prefix)`. Boring.

#### Option 1 (use this if there are non-numerical prefixes)

Let `k` be the minimum prefix length. Use a `HashMap` where the **keys** are the **first `k` digits of each prefix** and the **items** are **linked lists** containing **the rest of each prefix**.

For instance, say you have prefixes `abcd`, `abce`, and `xyz`. Then you would store the following:

- `"abc"`-->`("d","e")`, where `("d","e")` is a linked list containing the elements `"d"` and `"e"`
- `"xyz"`-->`("")` (where `""` is the empty string).

Call this map `prefixes`, and use the following code to determine if a prefix is correct:

```
public boolean correctPrefix(String input){
    LinkedList check = prefix.get(input.substring(0,k))
    if (check != null){
        for (String n : check){
            if (input.substring(k).startsWith(check)) return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if it will be fast *enough* for your purposes, though you haven't told us exactly what those are; still, I don't know of anything *faster* in Java.

#### Option 2 (use this if all prefixes are numerical, or you're using SE7)

Use a `switch` statement. Or rather, use multiple switch statements, one for each possible prefix length. For instance, suppose you have the prefixes `1901`, `1902`, and `20050`:

```
public boolean correctPrefix(String input){
    int pVal;
    pVal = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,4));
    switch (pval){
    case 1901: return true;
    case 1902: return true;
    }
    pVal = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,5));
    switch (pval){
    case 20050: return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will be a lot more code, but I suspect it will be much faster assuming you have enough prefixes with the same length. Note that if a `switch` statement doesn't have very many possible cases, it won't actually be compiled as a true `switch` statement but as a series of `if/else` blocks, which will cause it to be fairly slow. You should do some mucking about with this, though, and see what you get; it might be worthwhile to throw in some bogus `case [wrongprefix]: return false;` statements in, because believe it or not they can actually speed things up.

Actually, as of SE7, switch statements **can** be used with strings. I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it's an option.

Alternatively, if you're using something prior to SE7, you could try....

#### Option 3 (how to cheat)

You can actually pass a radix to `parseInt`, meaning that if you have letters in your prefixes **but** they're case-insensitive, you can use `Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,4),36)` to get a valid integer value, which you can then use with `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to store the prefix in a HashMap and the value should be a linked list. I am assuming the same prefix can get tagged with various numbers like 19011234 190123444.

Answer (score 1):

Are the prefixes the same length?

If so, you could hash all the prefixes.

When you encounter a new input you would extract the first x digits.

You would look for the presence of the first x digits in the hash - an O(1) operation if the hash is designed well.

Comment: Thanks... The prefixes can be of different length also.

Comment: Even if they are of different lengths, how many different lengths would you expect? If there are just 3 or 4 different lengths, it might still make sense to go ahead with the approach I talked about. You would just have to transform the input to different possible prefix lengths and try.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have (relatively) small integers, you could use a sparse array of booleans, where your prefixes will act as indexes.

Alternatively, a `HashSet` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `HashSet` and add these 4 values in it. and then parse your input values to get first four integers and call HashSet `contains()` method, that will return true/false.